# send a post request of array into directus

Tags: reactjs, request, fetch, directus

I want to send a form and one of the things is a checkbox which is array according to the get request... I have tried in postman.. it works.. but in React.

I have tried to send data using the form and I get stuck after trying to send the array to the directus.

```
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      nama: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      telepon: this.state.telepon,
      program: [1],
      tanggal_lahir: this.state.tanggal_lahir,
      tempat_lahir: this.state.tempat_lahir,
    })
})
```

if I comment on the program it works.

I also tried `["1"]` or `"1"` or `1`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

this is silly... i got the wrong syntax..

i just change `program: [1]`, to `program_yang_dipilih: ["1", "3"]`